# Model fit after inverse regression and forward stagewise on residuals

Tags: r, regression, lars, inverse-prediction

I work with prediction of height based on genetic information.  The data is several hundred thousand data points from every organism, but a simplified version could be:

```
df = data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
height = c(2, 4, 6, 10, 12), 
gene1 = c(0.2, -0.3, -0.6, -0.7, -0.8), 
gene2 = c(0.4, -0.2, -0.4, -0.2, -0.6),
gene3 = c(-0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7))
```

I became interested in doing inverse regression on gene 1, since the residual values I obtain from that gives different results than using height as response. So the regression is:

```
model1 <- lm(gene1 ~ height, data=df)
```

I then take the residual values from this and do forward stagewise (LARS package) after removing gene1 from the dataframe:

```
resid <- model1$residuals
resid <- as.data.frame(resid)
Stagewise <- lars(df, resid$resid, type="forward.stagewise", max.steps=2, use.Gram=FALSE)
```

After doing this, I’m interested in fitting the model so I can get a value for height (and run the test set). Since I am using the residual values for the stagewise procedure, I am not sure how to obtain this.

Assistance greatly appreciated!

Comment: is the first regression done to remove the effect of gene1 on height? If so then most likely you are doing the regression wrongly. Otherwise your model doesn't make sense for me

Comment: No, the first regression is done inverse since the residuals simply seem to make more sense (downstream in a biological sense). Gene1 is a gene of primary interest. So in stead of having "height" on the Y-axis I have "gene1" on the Y-axis, and when I perform stagewise from the residuals of this (inverse regression) I get "better" results.